# Python requests: Upload image as byte array

Tags: c#, python, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, python-requests

**Goal:** Using asp.net web/api, define the signature that allows the upload of images via byte array, and test the operation with python requests.

**Problem:** I can't seem to get a response other than Unsupported Media Type

**Allowances:** I have control of the API, so I can modify if needed as long as it ultimately ends up as a byte array so I don't have to re-write the business layer

**My first stab:**

*(ASP.Net Api-Controller) Method):*

```
[Route("api/scenes/{id}/images")]
[Route("api/v0/scenes/scenes/{id}/images")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddImageToScene(long id, string type, [FromBody] byte[] value)
```

*My Python Script:*

```
# FORM THE FULLY QUALIFIED PATH
file_name = name + ".png"
path = os.path.join(resource_path, file_name)

# SEND THE COMMAND
files = {'image': (file_name, open(path, 'rb'), 'image/png')}
url = helper.baseUri + self.route
requests.post(url, files=files)
```

**Response (from my own output printer):**

> [ERROR] Api call returned with error 415   [ERROR] Unsupported Media
>   Type

**Conclusion:**
I've tried several variations, and yes I've looked at the docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), but I just don't seem smart enough to make it work. I suspect I don't really want to call it an image since I'm breaking it into bytes - but I don't see any MIME options that I think would be appropriate.

Comment: have you tried `application/octet-stream` as the media type?

Comment: @flaschbier : Thank you, just tried it and it seems to give the same error. files = {'image': (file_name, open(path, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')}

Answer (score 0):

For posterity sake, though a change from my initial approach, I did get the following to work. Do note that I don't believe that I need the type here as a parameter as I should be able to pull the media type from the request headers...I just haven't got to it yet.

```
public HttpResponseMessage AddImageToScene2(long id, string type)
    {
        SceneHandler handler = null;

        try
        {


            var content = Request.Content;
            var asBytes = content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

            using (handler = new SceneHandler()) // <-- my own custom class
            {
                var image = new ImageNewOrUpdate(asBytes, type);
                var response = handler.AddImage(id, image.Value, image.ImageType);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, response);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new HttpErrorResponseFactory(Request, ex, handler).GetResponse();
        }
    }
```